# how should I design tables to store a data in a specific format based on user nationality?

Tags: database, locale

let's say I have a data regarding size that differs based on user nationality, example trousers size.
For example Italy uses different sizing scheme from USA.
So I want to ask the user to insert his trouser size based on the sizing scheme of his nationality.
Let's say the user selects Italy, so the user is presented a list of possible italian trousers sizes.
How do I do that based on stored nationality in user_data table?

example:

### user table

user_name
user_nationality
user_trouser_size

### size table

italian_sizes
american_sizes

when registering the user sets his nationality, for example "italian"
then when asked to chose a size for his trousers the system will return automatically italian_sizes from the size table and store it for the user account.

What tables do I need and how do I reference between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way to store them. It's by no means the only way, nor necessarily the best, but I think it's reasonably sound and understandable.
The code is for Sql Server but other database systems should be very similar.

```
create table Sizes
(
    CountryCode NVARCHAR(3),
    Size INT,
    constraint PX_Sizes primary key(CountryCode,Size)
    //other fields go here
)

create table Users
(
    ID INT,
    CountryCode NVARCHAR(3),
    Size INT,
    //other fields go here
    constraint PK_Users primary key (ID),
    constraint FK_Users_Sizes foreign key
        (CountryCode,Size) references Sizes(CountryCode,Size)

)

//sample data
    insert into Sizes select 'USA',42
    insert into Sizes select 'USA',43
    insert into Sizes select 'ITA',18
    insert into Sizes select 'ITA',19

    Insert into Users select 1,'ITA',19
    Insert into Users select 2,'USA',43
```

Now at first glance this looks like duplication of data, but really what it's doing is using the `Sizes` table as the data source for the list of sizes for a particular Nationality (`CountryCode`) but *also* as a referential constraint for the size data in `Users`.

So it's not possible to end up with invalid data in the `Users` table because the constraints prevent you from entering an invalid `CountryCode/Size` combination. You can enforce further referential integrity by making `SizeUsers.CountryCode` a Foreign Key reference to a `Countries` table, for example.

The advantage of using this structure as opposed to having individual columns for the sizes in each country is that it becomes easy to extend when you need to add more countries - you don't need to change the `Sizes` table, just add more entries with the appropriate country code.

To get all the sizes for a Nationality you just do something like

```
SELECT * FROM Sizes where CountryCode='USA' ORDER BY Size ASC
```

Hope that helps.